# Display multiple buttons side-by-side by using single button iOS Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

In stackoverflow is showing only 2 or 3 button ie., through storyboard

Images: https://ibb.co/gSFQX2k

Comment: I need to display like the above image. If anyone know the answer please response as soon as possible. I need it's urgent.

Comment: You can use this library: https://github.com/ElaWorkshop/TagListView

Comment: use `UIStackView` to easily get your result

Comment: use UICollectionView for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
 var consolebtn = [UIButton]()
 var x = Int()
 x = 0

 @IBAction func pushButton(sender: UIButton) {
     let btn = UIButton() 
     btn.frame = CGRect(x:x, y:10, width:10, height:10)
     btn.setTitle("Button Title",for: .normal)
     consolebtn.append(btn)
     view.addSubview(btn)  
     x += 20 // 10 is width & 10 is gap between two button
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]Try going through blog, It uses collection view to solve the problem

[https://medium.freecodecamp.org/how-to-make-height-collection-views-dynamic-in-your-ios-apps-7d6ca94d2212](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kt5HT.png)